# Different HttpComponent-Version on Android

Tags: android, apache

Is it possible to use a different version of Apache's HttpComponents as installed within the used SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to change the package name though, in order not to clash with the system one. You can use [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) or a similar tool to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a repackaged httpclient for android here.
[httpclientandroidlib](http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do without needing to change the jar file.

In Eclipse,

1 right click your project name and click Properties

2 click Java Build Path on the left side

3 click Libraries on the right side

4 add org/apache/http/** to Access rules, as it is shown in the picture. You need to add ** as it means everything including folders under the path. If you only use one *, it means all files under the path, not including the folders.

Also, there is an Access rules under Android.jar, but you can't add rules to it. I had already done that and found out that it didn't save when you closed the window, so it would not take any effects.

[image]

5 then click Order and Export and put httpcomponents jar file to the top or at least upper than Android.

[image]

6 click ok and go to your java files. alt+shift+o to rebuild dependencies. If there is anything still shows errors like "no method is found ...". Just delete that line and retype. Sometimes the editor still remembers the httpcomponents that are in Android.jar and you need to retype to refresh him. ^_^